# how to properly delete or update activities on bot framework?

Tags: botframework

I can't find a guide on documentation for make this possible. 
I tried to use `TurnContext.UpdateActivity`, but I'm getting an error.

My code:

```
IMessageActivity responseActivity = MessageFactory.Text("Test ctm");
responseActivity.Id = userProfile.messageToDelete;
responseActivity.Conversation = turnContext.Activity.Conversation;
responseActivity.ServiceUrl = turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl;
//await turnContext.DeleteActivityAsync(userProfile.messageToDelete, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
await turnContext.UpdateActivityAsync(responseActivity, cancellationToken);
```

The last line throws the exception:

> Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound''

What could be wrong? Can you share any code sample?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code and errors as plain text, indented 4 spaces. The screenshots are unreadable.

Comment: You have edited your question in such a way that you are now referencing a totally different problem. Your original question used my screenshot from [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/2388), which you've also commented on. Since you say it's working in Teams, do you consider your issue to be resolved?

Comment: Sorry bro,i saw your post and i get your screenshot 'cause i couldn't access to my laptop until yesterday when i edited the post. I needed to get answer to that problem, for that reason i posted here. The issue is resolved to work on teams, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Emulator is built on top of Web Chat, and unfortunately, Web Chat does not support updating or deleting activities at the moment. For more details, take a look at this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/ac5b6be8601207b05e2196fc3b0b2f07698961b0/packages/core/src/reducers/activities.js#L99) in Web Chat's source code and this open [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1384) in the Web Chat repository for adding support for `deleteActivity` and `updateActivity`.

Hope this helps!